# Django - TailwindCSS won't load some attributes

Tags: python, css, django, tailwind-css

I'm having issues when it comes to using some attributes with Django and TailwindCSS.
Let's take this table for example:

```html
                    <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                        <table class="w-full text-lg text-left text-gray-500 rounded-2xl mt-4 dark:text-gray-400">
                            <thead class="rounded-2xl text-lg text-white uppercase bg-[#68BA9E] dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Report title
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Company
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Brand (if any)
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Go to report
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for report in reports %}
                                <tr class="bg-white border-b text-center dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                                    <th scope="row"
                                        class="h-19 px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {{ report.title }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        {{ report.company }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        {% if report.brand %}
                                            {{ report.brand }}
                                        {% else %}
                                            -
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        <a href="{% url 'tool:single-report' slug=report.slug %}">Access</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Gives the following:
[image: Text]

But when I try to change the `bg-color` from:

```html
<thead class="rounded-2xl text-lg text-white uppercase bg-[#68BA9E] dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
```

To:

```html
 <thead class="rounded-2xl text-lg text-white uppercase bg-red-700 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
```

The new color won't load. It gives:
[image: Text]

I don't understand why I'm getting nothing. In my configuration, following tasks are running:

- The server is running with `python manage.py runserver`
- TailwindCSS is running with `python manage.py tailwind start`
- Livereload is running with `python manage.py livereload`

I also clear my cache with CMD+Shift+R.

I'm also having troubles with some margins and paddings that won't apply. I even bought the [plugin Devtools for TailwindCSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-for-tailwind-css/mihalpimkkhhigoielhempcamoffhfij). When I edit an attribute with Chrome inspector and this plugin, it's working. But when it's in my code, the new color won't load.
Has this ever happened to you?

**Update:**
Here is the complete code:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="flex-1 pt-8 pb-5 max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

        <div class="w-100 mb-10">
            <div>
                {% if nb_reports == 0 %}

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-400" fill="none"
                             viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                             stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" aria-hidden="true">>
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                  d="M9 17v-2m3 2v-4m3 4v-6m2 10H7a2 2 0 01-2-2V5a2 2 0 012-2h5.586a1 1 0 01.707.293l5.414 5.414a1 1 0 01.293.707V19a2 2 0 01-2 2z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <h3 class="mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">No reports</h3>
                        <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">Get started by creating a new report.</p>
                        <div class="mt-6">
                            <a href="{% url 'tool:create-report' %}"
                               class="inline-block items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-xl text-white bg-[#195266] hover:bg-[#23647a] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                New report
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% else %}

                    <div>
                        <h2 class="text-xl leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Create report</h2>
                        <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">Find all your created reports below.</p>
                    </div>





                    <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                        <table class="w-full text-lg text-left text-gray-500 rounded-2xl mt-4 dark:text-gray-400">
                            <thead class="rounded-2xl text-lg text-white uppercase bg-red-700 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Report title
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Company
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Brand (if any)
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                    Go to report
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for report in reports %}
                                <tr class="bg-white border-b text-center dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                                    <th scope="row"
                                        class="h-19 px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {{ report.title }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        {{ report.company }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        {% if report.brand %}
                                            {{ report.brand }}
                                        {% else %}
                                            -
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        <a href="{% url 'tool:single-report' slug=report.slug %}">Access</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Hi @RosePark, I just edited my post to include the complete code of my template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We finally managed to solve this issue.
The problem was that I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` which created the following directory : `static > css > dist > styles.css`. `django-tailwind` created the same repository under the `theme` folder. Every time I tried to restart the server, the wrong `styles.css` was taken into account. So by changing the name of the first folder, it enabled me to load the correct CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me. YOu can see here for the code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/45ADIccwkt) .

If the `bg` class is working for any custom color, then it should also work with `red-700`. Else you can check if there's any typo.

You can also add `!` likr this `!bg-red-700` to make this class important.

Lastly try to restart the server,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe the answer is correct but I'm still having the same issue on my side. I did try to restart the server, it did not change anything.

Comment: I also amazed to see that if `bg-[#68BA9E] ` is working then why `bg-red-700` is not? Check and update the tailwind to the latest version.

Comment: I tried to do it, also to switch to the 2.2.0 version but I'm still getting the issue. I installed Tailwind with `django-tailwind` and I'm running on localhost. I don't know if it is related?

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by changing the templates directory in my settings.py file from the template folder I was using before adding tailwind to the theme/templates folder that was created when setting up tailwind.

in settings.py file from this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...,
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        ..., 
    }
],
```

to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...,
        'DIRS': ['theme/templates'],
        ...,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well after running `python manage.py collectstatic`. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72965602/17767334), there is a conflict between the folder at `static/css/dist/styles.css` and `theme/static/css/dist/styles.css`.

As suggested, when I changed the name of one of the files in `static/css/dist/styles.css`, the compilation when I re-ran `python manage.py tailwind start` worked straight away.